# How cache data from SQL-database with python?

Tags: python, caching

I have queries result from Postgresql which I want to be cached. I can't use external soft like memcached. How I can do it with python with standard library? Or may be with third party python module.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a 3rd party library you could take a look at [dogpile.cache](https://dogpilecache.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/usage.html). It will allow you to cache things like data from SQL databases in memory, and in addition you can choose from different [backends](https://dogpilecache.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/api.html#module-dogpile.cache.backends.memory). This is good in case you want to use something more scalable in the future.